Rendering a pyvis graph inside python dash app
I want to make a dash app to visualize some networks, stored in a database, according to a user input query. Below I have given my code. The pyvis graph is not showing when I run the Dash server. I can see that the html file is being generated properly, but the box is blank when I run the server.
How can I resolve this issue? Is there any other way to do it. I am open to using any other library as well.
import pyvis as pv
from pyvis.network import Network
import dash
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from db_connection import connect_db

def get_subgraph(query):
    conn = connect_db()
    res = conn.execute(query)
    G = res.get_networkx_obj()
    return (G)

def visualize_subgraph(subgraph_G):
    net = Network()
    net.from_nx(subgraph_G)
    html_net = net.generate_html()
    return (html_net)

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
navbar = dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Container(
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.Col(
                dbc.NavbarBrand(
                    [  
                        html.Span("Network Explorer", className="ms-2")
                    ],
                    className="d-flex align-items-center"
                ),
                width="auto"  
            ),
            className="w-100", 
            align="center"
        ),
        fluid=True
    ),
    color="light",
    dark=False,  
       sticky="top",
       className="p-2", 
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
   navbar,
   # First Row: Search Box
   dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([
           dbc.Card([
               dbc.CardBody([
                   dcc.Textarea(
                       id='search-input',
                       placeholder='Enter your search here...',
                       style={'width': '100%', 'height': 100},
                       className='mb-3'
                   ),
                   dbc.Button('Submit Query', id='submit-button', n_clicks=0, color="primary")
               ])
           ])
       ], width=12)
   ], className='mb-4'),
    # Second Row: Network Visualization
   dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(id="graph-output", className="mt-4", children=[
                    html.Iframe(
                    id='default-iframe',
                    width="100%",
                    height="600px"
                )
            ])
        ])
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output("default-iframe", "srcDoc"),
    Input("submit-button", "n_clicks"),
    State("query-input", "value")
)

def update_output(n_clicks, query):
    if not n_clicks or not query:
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    subgraph = get_subgraph(query)
    graph_html = visualize_subgraph(subgraph)
    return (graph_html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


You should return html_net.html
